# Preferrable way to send push messeges?

Tags: pubsub, push

I am making a chat-app using the XMPP protocol and ejabberd as XMPP server. I want to build a push notification functionality for the app. The app is similar to WhatsApp. I came to know three different techniques on FCM to deliver push notifications:

1. Topic
2. Registration token
3. Device group messaging

I am confused which technique should I go for. Although I have studied the latency and throughput. The first one is great for throughput, as mentioned in Google's documentation. But I am unable to decide whether my app should focus more on latency or throughput.

Comment: Seeing as you're using eJabber, why don't you make use of pub/sub?

Comment: Because in pubsub every one should have the authoritiy to publish on the node for which particular user will receive notifications . Also on pubsub of FCM it has a limit that an app instanc can only subscribe to 2000 topics so no more then 2000 contact's node can be subscribed . (That is similar to Topic in my question).